# QGraphicsView blocks drop event in my textedit

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview, qtextedit

i have following problem.

I have a QGraphicsView in my scene and I have added one QTextEdit, my problem starts when I try to insert a picture in textedit through the drop event.

When I drag the image to the textedit, the graphicsView leaves blocked the event, do not let me drop the image.

Comment: is this happening only if you drag over the `QGraphicsView`?

Comment: when I drag the image and the event enters my area editor (TextEdit) is locked, only that which is within textedit a graphicsview. I auditioned for another textedit without graphicsview event occurred and correctly.

Comment: ok, am i getting this right that you have a `QGraphicsView` inside your `QTextEdit` and want to insert the image to the `QTextEdit` and not into the `QGraphicsView` ?

Comment: If you're adding a QTextEdit to the QGraphicsScene, it will be creating a QGraphicsProxyWidget for you. You may find that it's this widget that's actually blocking, not the QGraphicsView.

Comment: No, I have a QTextEdit inside a QGraphicsView, want to insert the image in QTextEdit.

My hierarchy: QgraphicsView >> QGraphicsScene >>QTextEdit

Understand?

Comment: Merlin In fact, not created the QProxyItemWidgetNa actually created the QGraphicsProxyWidget not only utilized:

scene-> addWidget (textedit);

Comment: @Merlin069 thanks for pointing to that :D. the other thing could be, that on the `QGraphicsView` mousetracking is disabled...